# Mongo find by regext match end of string

Tags: mongodb

I have something like this on postgresql :

```
SQL> select * from sample ;

        ID IDENTITY
---------- --------------------
         1 9898
         2 129898
         3 AABB9898
         4 1234
         5 ABCD
```

**Question :** How to convert this select to mongo query ?

```
> select * from sample where '545454129898' like '%' || identity ; 

        ID IDENTITY
---------- --------------------
         1 9898
         2 129898
```

I have this same data on mongo database :

```
> db.sample.find();
[
  { _id: ObjectId("654d5e00b560e4fd57bde48a"), identity: '9898' },
  { _id: ObjectId("654d5e0cb560e4fd57bde48b"), identity: '129898' },
  { _id: ObjectId("654d5e17b560e4fd57bde48c"), identity: 'AABB9898' },
  { _id: ObjectId("654d5e17b560e4fd57bde48d"), identity: 'AABB9898' },
  { _id: ObjectId("654d5e17b560e4fd57bde48e"), identity: '1234' },
  { _id: ObjectId("654d5e17b560e4fd57bde48f"), identity: 'ABCD' }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, you should use the `$expr` operator to work with [`$regexMatch`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) (aggregation operator) to build the regex string with the `identity` field.

Hence this will construct the regex by matching the input value that ends with the `identity` value.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $regexMatch: {
      input: "545454129898",
      regex: {
        $concat: [
          "$identity",
          {
            $literal: "$"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wHGn_zbDhlo)